# CypherGremlinClient query runs very slow

Tags: java, neo4j, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I am trying to run opencypher query using CypherGremlinClient.

this is how i initiate CypherGremlinClient.

```
 org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration configuration = new BaseConfiguration();
        configuration.setProperty("port", neptuneProp.getPort());
        configuration.setProperty("hosts", neptuneProp.getOpencypherhost());
        configuration.setProperty("connectionPool.enableSsl", "true");
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.open(configuration);
        Client gremlinClient = cluster.connect();
        return CypherGremlinClient.translating(gremlinClient);
```

My query is

```
MATCH p=(n)-[r]->(d) WHERE ID(n) = '123' RETURN n,r
```

this returns results with all attributes including ~id,~label which I need it for node and for Edges i am looking into ~id, _inV, _outV. but this query is running slow, most of the time I get memory error from neptune server.

Other side i am using below method which is executing query faster but does not return attributes that i am looking for.

```
    Config  neptunePropOpencypherConfig = Config.builder()
                    .withConnectionTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .withMaxConnectionPoolSize(1000)
                    .withDriverMetrics()
                    .withLeakedSessionsLogging()
                    .withEncryption()
                    .withTrustStrategy(Config.TrustStrategy.trustSystemCertificates())
                    .build();
GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://" neptune.getHost() + ":" + neptuneProp.getPort(), neptunePropOpencypherConfig)
```

please help me to run my query faster with CypherGremlinClient or help me to get all other attributes using

```
Transaction readTx = readDiver.session().beginTransaction();
            Result results =  readTx.run("MATCH p=(n)-[r]->(d) WHERE ID(n) = '" + wgiId + "' RETURN n,r");
```

or if you know then suggest another approach.

I am looking for this kind of response.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "n": {
        "~id": "123",
        "~entityType": "node",
        "~labels": [
          "ontology"
        ],
        "~properties": {
          "lastrevid": 0,
          "P98": "1151332690",
          "labels": "{ \"de\" : [ \"Ivan Shedoff\" ] }",
          "aliases": "{ \"de\" : [ \"Ivan Shedoff\" ] }",
          "description": "{ }",
          "P26": "4.61517E+19"
        }
      },
      "r": {
        "~id": "123$11d27a77-1227-422c-9134-6e96d1cb7c79",
        "~entityType": "relationship",
        "~start": "123",
        "~end": "Q3",
        "~type": "claim",
        "~properties": {
          "claimCode": "P5"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I see that you have asked several questions on Neptune and openCypher, please feel free to email neptune-opencypher-feedback@amazon.com if you want to have a more in-depth conversation.

Answer (score 3):

Neptune now supports openCypher as query language, see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-opencypher-queries.html).  Support is currently in lab mode but soon to be GA.

Using the `openCypher` endpoint would be much easier than trying to do a translation.  If you use the HTTPS endpoint you will get a result that is almost exactly what you specified above, an example is below

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "a": {
        "~id": "22",
        "~entityType": "node",
        "~labels": [
          "airport"
        ],
        "~properties": {
          "desc": "Seattle-Tacoma",
          "lon": -122.30899810791,
          "runways": 3,
          "type": "airport",
          "country": "US",
          "region": "US-WA",
          "lat": 47.4490013122559,
          "elev": 432,
          "city": "Seattle",
          "icao": "KSEA",
          "code": "SEA",
          "longest": 11901
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```